# Mule Community edition vs Enterprise edition - Feature Comparison?

Tags: comparison, mule, esb, enterprise

This should be a simple 'google' ... but I have drawn a blank. I assume it must be out there somewhere, can anyone help me find it?

**I need a simple comparison that tells me what is in and what is out of the community edition vs the enterprise edition?**

*For example the DataMapper is not included in Community, but this is not clear until you try to deploy, I'd really like to save a lot of wasted effort upfront.

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MuleSoft provides a list of comparisons and features here:
http://www.mulesoft.com/platform/soa/mule-esb-enterprise

This details that Datamapper is enterprise only. It has a blanket statement around enterprise connectors, but you can view which are enterprise or community via mulesoft.org/connectors?class=premium

Some transports, (mainly JDBC) have enterprise equivalents which are documented on the individual transports documentation pages: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JDBC+Transport+Reference

Comment: Thats useful, thanks. But we really need a deeper level of granularity... I need the list that says DataMapper=no, SFTP=yes, etc. At the build element level I guess. At the moment I need to build and deploy to find out what wont work. Thanks

Comment: The above list does say Datamapper = no. The core of Mule including it's transports such as SFTP is open source and included in the community edition(with exception to the JDBC transport which has an additional enterprise jdbc transport) As for enterprise connectors etc. You can view which are enterprise or community via http://www.mulesoft.org/connectors?class=premium

Comment: Thanks... yes, I didnt see the datamapper reference... I was expectign a long list... but in conjunction with the connector search this gets me somewhere useful. Many Thanks.... In your view what is the key bits we loose on community edition?

Comment: imho Datamapper, the Mule Management Console, clustering/HA and mainly the support from Mulesoft. Transformation can be done in many other ways than Datamapper and the same for clustering and monitoring etc. There's a good thread on the mule group on LinkedIn: https://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&gid=958797&type=member&item=5794722458095345668&trk=groups_items_see_more-0-b-ttl You will need to join the group if you are not already a member.

Answer (score 4):

Bumping an old thread, but this page provides a good simple list with simple supported/not supported and also the impact areas of such feature not being included in CE.

http://www.whishworks.com/blog/mule-esb-community-vs-enterprise-edition/

However, adding the same content here so that if the link becomes dead, the content doesn't get lost. Simply hit Run code snippet button > Full page to see the complete table.

```html
<p><strong>High Availability and Performance</strong>
</p>
<table class="matrix" style="height: 247px;" width="650">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="173"><b>Feature</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Community</b><b> Edition</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Enterprise Edition (G) / (S)</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Enterprise Edition (P)</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Impact</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">High Availability</td>
      <td width="173">No Support</td>
      <td width="173">No Support</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Message Loss and Transaction failure</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">Resilience</td>
      <td width="173">No Support</td>
      <td width="173">No Support</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Impact on effort to take care of state full&nbsp; and failure scenarios</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">Caching</td>
      <td width="173">No Support</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Performance Impact</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Development</strong>
</p>
<table class="matrix" width="650">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="173"><b>Feature</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Community</b><b> Edition</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Enterprise Edition (G) / (S)</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Enterprise Edition (P)</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Impact</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">Anypoint Templates</td>
      <td width="173">No Support</td>
      <td width="173">No Support</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Saves development and design effort by using templates. Guesstimated to be 40 to 60% time saving depending on how close the use case matches to the template.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">Transaction Management</td>
      <td width="173">No Support</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Data loss and Impact on development effort</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">Batch Manager</td>
      <td width="173">No Support</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Impact on Development &amp; Support Effort</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">Batch Process component</td>
      <td width="173">No Support</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Impact on Development &amp; Support Effort</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">JDBC Enterprise Connector</td>
      <td width="173">No Support</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">for handling Batch statements, used in Data Integration project. Performance hit.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">Anypoint Datamapper</td>
      <td width="173">No Support</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Impact on Development</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Operational Support</strong>
</p>
<table class="matrix" width="650">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="173"><b>Feature</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Community</b><b> Edition</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Enterprise Edition (G) / (S)</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Enterprise Edition (P)</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Impact</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">Mule Management Console</td>
      <td width="173">No Support</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Impact on Support</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">SLA and email Alerts</td>
      <td width="173">No Support</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Impact on Support and Availability</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">SNMP Monitoring</td>
      <td width="173">No</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Impact on Support and Availability</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">HTTP Polling</td>
      <td width="173">No</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Impact on Support and Availability. Mule provides Http polling of service for availability.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">Deployment Management</td>
      <td width="173">No Support</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Impact on Support</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Security</strong>
</p>
<table class="matrix" width="650">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="173"><b>Feature</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Community</b><b> Edition</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Enterprise Edition (G) / (S)</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Enterprise Edition (P)</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Impact</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">Role based security</td>
      <td width="173">Not Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Major effort to custom develop</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">Oauth 2.0 – Secure Token Provider</td>
      <td width="173">Not Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Major effort to custom develop</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">Message Encryption</td>
      <td width="173">Not Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Major effort to custom develop</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">SAML 2.0 Module</td>
      <td width="173">Not Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Major effort to custom develop</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">Secure Property Holder</td>
      <td width="173">Not Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Keeps password and other confidential text in encrypted format. This cannot be custom built as it links directly to your endpoint.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">IP Based Filtering</td>
      <td width="173">Not Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">IP based filter is available in EE version for filtering endpoints based on inbound IP and requests can be filtered using LDAP.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Support</strong>
</p>
<table class="matrix" width="650">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="173"><b>Feature</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Community</b><b> Edition</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Enterprise Edition (G) / (S)</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Enterprise Edition (P)</b>
      </td>
      <td width="173"><b>Impact</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">License</td>
      <td width="173">Free</td>
      <td width="173">Purchase Minimum 2 Cores</td>
      <td width="173">Purchase Minimum 4 (2+2) for HA</td>
      <td width="173">Licence Cost</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">Hardened Code</td>
      <td width="173">No Support</td>
      <td width="173">Yes</td>
      <td width="173">Yes</td>
      <td width="173">Impact on stability and performance</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">SLA</td>
      <td width="173">Forums</td>
      <td width="173">8/5, 24 Hours Response Time</td>
      <td width="173">24/7, 2 Hours Response Time</td>
      <td width="173">Impact on support</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="173">Hot patches &amp; Service packs</td>
      <td width="173">No Support</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Supported</td>
      <td width="173">Impact on support and availability</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

-Shanky G.